# Given Range of a Function, Find the Function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers so that as $x$ varies over all real numbers, the range of the function

$$y=\frac{x^2+ax+b}{x^2+2x+3}$$

is the interval $−5≤y≤4$. Find $a+b$.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you used the algebraic-geometry tag?

Comment: What've you tried?Did you choose the tag randomly?

Comment: I didn't know what tag to put it under, sorry. And I've tried manipulating the equation, and found $a$ and $b$ that work, but they were both negative, -10 and -15 respectively

Comment: Obviously $a=2$ and $b=3$ does not work, since that makes $y=1$, which is not $-5$ or any of the integers between $-5$ and $4$.

Comment: Yes, sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: @Pakquebchsoflwty but the function $y = 1$ does lie in the range $-5\leq y \leq 4$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$y(x^2+2x+3)=x^2+ax+b,$$
i.e.
$$(y-1)x^2+(2y-a)x+3y-b=0.$$
Since the discriminant has to be non-negative, we have
$$(2y-a)^2-4(y-1)(3y-b)\ge 0,$$
i.e.
$$y^2+\frac{a-b-3}{2}y+\frac{4b-a^2}{8}\le 0.$$
We want this to be $(y+5)(y-4)\le 0$, so solving$$\frac{a-b-3}{2}=5-4,\qquad \frac{4b-a^2}{8}=5\times (-4)$$
gives $a=14,b=9$.

Answer (score 1):

$a = 14$ and $b = 9$, so $a + b = 23$.

[image]

Here's how you solve this problem:  First calculate the derivative with respect to $x$:

${d y \over d x} = -\frac{(a-2) x^2-3 a+2 (b-3) x+2 b}{(x (x+2)+3)^2}$

Then set this derivative to zero.  (There will be two solutions, as is clear from the functional form, and from the particular solution graph.)

Then you have two equations in two unknowns ($a$ and $b$).  Solve under the constraint that both are positive.